# How can I convert a plain array into an array with objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

in my vuejs project I'm working on, the information from the api comes in the form of a flat array. I need to edit this incoming data and convert it to the following format.
For example, I need to arrange the parent id of an object to be the id of its parent item.

i tried this way but the tree is returning as empty

```
convertToTree(data) {
  const tree = [];
  const mapped = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
    mapped[data[i].id] = data[i];
    mapped[data[i].id].children = [];
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
    if (mapped[data[i].parentId]) {
      mapped[data[i].parentId].children.push(mapped[data[i]]);
    } else {
      tree.push(mapped[data[i]]);
    }
  }

  return tree;
},
```

How can I solve this problem, I am waiting for your ideas.

data from api

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "parentId": 0,
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "parentId": 0,
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "parentId": 0,
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "parentId": 3,
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "parentId": 3,
}, {
  "id": 6,
  "parentId": 4,
}, {
  "id": 7,
  "parentId": 4,
}, {
  "id": 8,
  "parentId": 5,
}, {
  "id": 9,
  "parentId": 5,
}, {
  "id": 10,
  "parentId": 0,
}
```

this is how i want to edit data

```
items: [{
    id: 1,
    parentId: 0,
    children: [{
      id: 10,
      parentId: 1,
    }, ],
    id: 2,
    parentId: 0,
    children: [],
    id: 3,
    parentId: 0,
    children: [{
        id: 4,
        parentId: 3,
        children: [{
            id: 6,
            parentId: 4,
            children: [],
          },
          {
            id: 7,
            parentId: 4,
            children: [],
          },
          {
            id: 8,
            parentId: 4,
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        parentId: 3,
        children: [{
            id: 9,
            parentId: 5,
            children: [],
          },
          {
            id: 10,
            parentId: 5,
            children: [],
          },
          {
            id: 11,
            parentId: 5,
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }, ],
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: What did you try? That there's a tree suggests that nodes (objects with `children`) can be formed with recursive function call.

Comment: Your desired output is invalid as it contains multiple id/parentId/children properties in the same object/at the same level.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to directly loop through the dataArray and push the child object into `parentObj.children`, then filter the dataArray to get all the root nodes of trees (Tree structures).

```
for (obj of dataArr) {
    if (obj.parentId) {
        let parent = dataArr.find((i) => i.id === obj.parentId);
        if (parent) {
            parent.children = [...parent.children || [], obj]
            // ↑ this creates an array if parent.children is undefined, avoiding error
        }
    }
}
```

By now, the dataArray becomes something like this:

```
0: {id: 1, parentId: 0}
1: {id: 2, parentId: 0}
2: {id: 3, parentId: 0, children: Array(2)}
3: {id: 4, parentId: 3, children: Array(2)}
4: {id: 5, parentId: 3, children: Array(2)}
5: {id: 6, parentId: 4}
6: {id: 7, parentId: 4}
7: {id: 8, parentId: 5}
8: {id: 9, parentId: 5}
9: {id: 10, parentId: 0}
```

Then, filter the dataArray by removing objects that got no parent.

```
let newData = dataArr.filter((obj) => !obj.parentId);
```

The result is an array with objects that are root nodes of tree structures.

```
0: {id: 1, parentId: 0}
1: {id: 2, parentId: 0}
2: {id: 3, parentId: 0, children: Array(2)}
3: {id: 10, parentId: 0}
```

`newData[2]`:

```
2:
children: Array(2)
    0:
    children: Array(2)
        0: {id: 6, parentId: 4}
        1: {id: 7, parentId: 4}
    id: 4
    parentId: 3
    1:
    children: Array(2)
        0: {id: 8, parentId: 5}
        1: {id: 9, parentId: 5}
    id: 5
    parentId: 3
id: 3
parentId: 0
```